# error upgrading centos 7.3 to 7.4

Tags: centos, upgrade

I've tried to upgrade my PC from Centos 7.3 to Centos 7.4, however I got the following error:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/pydoc3 from install of python34-3.4.5-4.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package python3-3.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/python3 from install of python34-3.4.5-4.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package python3-3.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/pyvenv from install of python34-3.4.5-4.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package python3-3.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz from install of python34-3.4.5-4.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package python3-3.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libpython3.so from install of python34-libs-3.4.5-4.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package python3-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

I've looked through the [release notes](https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS7#head-281c090cc4fbc6bb5c7d4cd82a266fce807eee7c)  and found nothing with respect to this issue in the section dealing with known issues. I did not find anything conclusive either while searching for this error on google.

Could someone please explain to me what's causing this error and how to solve it?

Many thanks,
Andrei

Comment: Remove python3-3.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64 and then upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just type this in your terminal:

`yum remove python3-libs-3.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64`
 
`yum remove python3-3.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64`

And try again

Kind regards